# nvme performance difference (OS dependent)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, linux-mint, nvme, hdparm

My laptop has two nvme drives:

- WDC PC SN730 SDBPNTY-512G-1101 (512GB)
- Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus (1TB)

I guess I have performance issue under Linux Mint 21.1 (5.15.0-56-generic). To determine performance under Linux I run:

```
sudo hdparm -t /dev/nvme0n1   ##WDC

 Timing buffered disk reads: 4028 MB in  3.00 seconds = 1342.26 MB/sec


sudo hdparm -t /dev/nvme1n1   ##Samsung

 Timing buffered disk reads: 8894 MB in  3.00 seconds = 2964.02 MB/sec
```

So, I decided to run tests for my both disks under Windows 11. the Performance of both drives is about the same, so I did not post two identical screenshots.
As you can see there is performance difference based on OS. Under Linux it has ~1300MB/sec but under Windows it has 3000+ MB/sec. Why so ? Thank you in advance

[image]

Btw here are smartctl output:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1   ##WDC

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       WDC PC SN730 SDBPNTY-512G-1101
Serial Number:                      *
Firmware Version:                   11190001
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x15b7
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x001b44
Total NVM Capacity:                 512.110.190.592 [512 GB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      8215
NVMe Version:                       1.3
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          512.110.190.592 [512 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            001b44 8b417829ec
Local Time is:                      Sun May 21 14:25:48 2023 +04
Firmware Updates (0x14):            2 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Log Page Attributes (0x1e):         Cmd_Eff_Lg Ext_Get_Lg Telmtry_Lg Pers_Ev_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         128 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     84 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     88 Celsius
Namespace 1 Features (0x02):        NA_Fields

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     5.50W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     3.50W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     3.00W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0700W       -        -    3  3  3  3     4000   10000
 4 -   0.0035W       -        -    4  4  4  4     4000   40000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         2
 1 -    4096       0         1

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        43 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    1%
Data Units Read:                    17.088.454 [8,74 TB]
Data Units Written:                 14.665.163 [7,50 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 230.753.892
Host Write Commands:                215.544.700
Controller Busy Time:               534
Power Cycles:                       817
Power On Hours:                     752
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   73
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      1
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
```

===================================

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme1n1   ##Samsung

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB
Serial Number:                      *
Firmware Version:                   2B2QEXM7
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 1.000.204.886.016 [1,00 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      4
NVMe Version:                       1.3
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          1.000.204.886.016 [1,00 TB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            461.030.297.600 [461 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            002538 5911b1ec25
Local Time is:                      Sun May 21 14:28:02 2023 +04
Firmware Updates (0x16):            3 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Log Page Attributes (0x03):         S/H_per_NS Cmd_Eff_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     7.80W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     6.00W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     3.40W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0700W       -        -    3  3  3  3      210    1200
 4 -   0.0100W       -        -    4  4  4  4     2000    8000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        44 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    12.387.466 [6,34 TB]
Data Units Written:                 9.430.383 [4,82 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 61.264.168
Host Write Commands:                29.762.033
Controller Busy Time:               252
Power Cycles:                       861
Power On Hours:                     482
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   215
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      1.470
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               44 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               42 Celsius
```

Comment: Are they both scanning exact same areas?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen yes, I tried to ran hdparm for the whole drive and also ran for specific partition with the same result

Comment: Yeah, I am still not convinced you can compare this reliably. You'd need some tool that offers native versions for both OS'es. See for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93791/benchmark-ssd-on-linux-how-to-measure-the-same-things-as-crystaldiskmark-does-i